# Join random won't work in my password generation script

Tags: python

I've written this simple python script for a starter project as I am interested in learning python. The goal is to ask the user for a length of their desired password, and then generate a secure password of that length. This is my code:

```
import random
import string

def randomword():
    possibles = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890-=_+!@#$%^&*(),./<>?'
    length = int(input("Password Length: "))
    return ''.join(random.choice(possibles) for i in range(length))

def pause():
    pause = input("Hit enter to continue.")


randomword()
pause()
```

However, when I run this, it asks for the length of the password, And then immediately skips over to the pause() function, like this:

`Password Length: 10
Hit enter to continue.`

Any help would be greatly appreciated. :)

Comment: If you want to generate passwords securely, the `random` module is not the tool for the job. `random.choice` does not provide the kind of guarantees needed for security work.

Comment: Also, you generated the password. Python didn't skip anything. Now, if you wanted to *see* the password, you'd have to actually tell Python to show it to you.

Comment: The script is not intended to be secure, it is intended to be practice. I'm simply wondering why the script seems to skip over the Join Random.

Comment: You said "The goal is to ... generate a secure password".

Comment: It didn't skip it, it executed it and returned the result. You didn't `print` it, though. Try `print(randomword())` instead of `randomword()`.

Comment: According to this example(https://pythontips.com/2013/07/28/generating-a-random-string/), I don't need to "tell Python to show it to me" as you said.

I admit that that is a discrepancy, and I apologize, I should have made my post clearer.

How do you suggest "getting python to show it to me"?

Comment: In interactive mode, python will print the result of each calculation as you type it. When you're running a program from a file, you don't get that behaviour.

Comment: Thanks, Blorgbeard, that worked.

Comment: Could you explain why `random` is not secure?

Comment: Random numbers as generated by `random` are actually not *that* random - they're reasonably unpredictable (and fast to generate), but they are not considered "cryptographically secure". Passwords generated by your program may exhibit patterns and structure which would reduce the work required to guess one of them. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographically_secure_pseudorandom_number_generator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, `pause` is called immediately after `randomword`. Its not that its skipping part of `randomword`, it's just executing it. When it returns a value, nothing is done with that value. You must add a `print` statement in order to see the returned result, like this:

```
import random
import string

def randomword():
    possibles = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890- 
=_+!@#$%^&*(),./<>?'
    length = int(input("Password Length: "))
    return ''.join(random.choice(possibles) for i in range(length))

def pause():
    pause = input("Hit enter to continue.")


print(randomword()) #Notice the print statement here
pause()
```

Also, as mentioned in the comments, this program is not fully secure.

Answer (score 1):

You also could do it this way

```
import random

def randomword():
    y = []
    possibles = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890-=_+!@#$%^&*(),./<>?'
    length = int(input("Password Length: "))

    for x in range(0, length):
        y.append(random.choice(possibles))

    print(''.join(y))

randomword()
input()
```